# PowerShell - Get only a string value

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

Hi how do I get only the value `test-staging-100` in the following dictionary

```
{ 
   "clusters": [
       "test-staging-100", 
       "test-local-1", 
       "test-dev-50" 
     ] 
}
```

when I ran this command

`$cluster = aws list-clusters | Select-String "test-staging"`

I keep getting `"test-staging-100",` . I don't want the quotation and comma but only **test-staging-100**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what the `aws` CLI returns is JSON text, so it's preferable to parse it into an object graph with [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) and act on that:

```
[string] $cluster = 
  @((aws list-clusters | ConvertFrom-Json).clusters) -match '^test-staging'
```

Note:

- The `@(...)` ensures that `-match` also works as intended - as a *filter* returning the *matching element(s)* - in case only *one* cluster happens to be returned.
- When `-match` acts as a filter, it invariably returns an *array*, even if only *one* element of the LHS array matches; type constraint `[string]` converts such a one-element array to a single string.
- If there's a chance that *multiple* elements match, more work is needed; to categorically use only the *first*, enclose the RHS of the assignment in `(...)[0]`

---

If you really wanted to use [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) to search the raw string output (which is ill-advised), you'd have to do something like:

```
$cluster = (aws list-clusters | Select-String 'test-staging[^"]+').Matches.Value
```